# Popup doesn't show images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have in my project a popup into my body tag and have a several data-role pages.

On each page have a button when the user click open this popup.

My problem is that I can open the popup window, but this popup contains a bxslider gallery for images and this images don't show.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#Paginasnocentro1234" data-rel="popup" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse" style="margin-right:70px" data-transition="none" id="blabla">Paginas</a>
```

Script:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#p36', function () {
$('#Paginasnocentro1234').hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '#blabla', function () {
$('#Paginasnocentro1234').toggle();
```

Popup:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="Paginasnocentro1234" data-theme="a" style="top:45px;position:absolute">
  <div class="slider">
<ul class="bxslider" id="paginacao">
  <li><a href="#p1"><img src="imagens/paginas/1.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p2"><img src="imagens/paginas/2.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p3"><img src="imagens/paginas/3.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p4"><img src="imagens/paginas/4.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p5"><img src="imagens/paginas/5.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p5"><img src="imagens/paginas/6.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p5"><img src="imagens/paginas/7.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p6"><img src="imagens/paginas/8.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p7"><img src="imagens/paginas/9.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, right click and inspect element in pop-up where the images "should" be. Find out what rule is being over-written. From there you'll see how to fix it.

Comment: exists an another way to hide this?